# MC.exe in msbuild

Tags: msbuild, wdk

How do I compile with mc.exe in the correct way. Currently I have a build step which runs the relevant command but looking at [developer network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh454227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There seems to be a better way.

I am not a expert with msbuild so please excuse how easy this question is. Googling has revealed no help

```
<Project 
    DefaultTargets="Build" 
    ToolsVersion="14.0" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="Message Source Files">
      <Extensions>mc;</Extensions>
      <UniqueIdentifier>{B796B525-44D3-4260-8C76-705DBADA1043}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <MessageCompile Include="a.mc">
        <GenerateBaselineResource>true</GenerateBaselineResource>
    </MessageCompile>
  </ItemGroup>  

  <Target Name="Build">
    <DontKnowWhatGoesHere Sources="@(MessageCompile)"/>  
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild build are usually extended via `.targets` files, that have to be included in the project, and they extend the existing build proces. [The WDK tasks for MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454288(v=vs.85).aspx) page confirms this:

> These command-line tools need to be exposed to MSBuild as tasks (contained in targets) so that they can be run during the build process.

The WDK MSDN page also has a help page on [Windows driver targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454290(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The WindowsDriver.Common.targets, WindowsDriver.masm.targets, and WindowsDriver.arm.targets files provide the targets that are necessary to build a driver.

A quick grep in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build` directory showed that the `MessageCompile` *target* (the step that actually processes the `MessageCompile` items) is defined in the `build\WindowsDriver.Common.targets` file.

After [importing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) the targets in your project you can do one of the following:

```
<Import 
   Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\build\WindowsDriver.Common.targets" />


<!-- Option A: -->
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="MessageCompile">
  <!-- no need to do anything, the dependency target should do the work -->
</Target>


<!-- Option B: -->
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="MessageCompile">
  <!-- Use the Mc task which is the actual wrapper around the .exe,
       see the .common.targets file for the list of all parameters -->
  <Mc
    Sources                         ="@(MessageCompile)"
    ToolExe                         ="$(MessageCompileToolExe)"
    ToolPath                        ="$(MessageCompileToolPath)"
    Generated 
  />
</Target>
```